# Understanding a comment about fixed points of rational functions

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions, fixed-points

Let $R(z)=\frac{a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_n z^n}{b_0+b_1z+\cdots +b_m z^m}$ where $a_nb_m \neq 0$ and $n >m$.  I understand that this fixes $\infty$ because the degree of the top is greater than the degree of the bottom.  Where I'm stuck is the following comment:

> In particular, $R(z)$ has exactly one fixed point at $\infty$ if one of the following are true: $n > m+1$, or if $n=m+1$ and $b_m \neq a_n$.

I'm just wondering if someone could provide some intuition to this.

**Latest and Greatest Attempt**

I  started pouring through all of the details of my book.  It got me thinking about the problem a bit more.  I stumbled on an easy example: $z^3+z$ has three fixed points at the origin.

For this problem I'm considering the mobius transform $g(z)=1/z$.  This way I'm sending $\infty$ to a finite point $0$.

So now I have $S(z)=g(R(g^{-1}(z)))$ and $S(\infty)=0.$  Unlike the example in my book, it seems like it would be rather difficult to find an explicit form for $S(z)$ that will enable me to compute the number at fixed points at $0$.

That's where I'm stuck.  How would I count the number of fixed points at $0$ in this case.

Comment: Is exactly one fixed point at $\infty$ supposed to rule out any others?  Consider $S(z)=\frac {z^4}{z^2+1}$ where $S(0)=0$

Comment: You're right.  Though the book has this remark as well.  At least I am not able to find a reason why that comment is true.

Comment: what is the definition of the multiplicity of a fixed point ?

Comment: $|R'(\xi)|$ is the multiplicity of a point.  The value of $|R'(\xi)|$ determines whether or not a point is attracting, indifferent, or repelling.

Comment: "In particular" suggests that something helpful was said in the preceding sentence ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  The gap is the discussion of multipliers, it's calculations, and how to define it at a point of infinity.  It's why I included it's calculations in the additional section.  I'm just not seeing the connection beween those assumptions, multipliers, and the $R(z)$ given.

Comment: I need a citation or a picture to believe that definition. Are you saying that the multiplicity may not be an integer but can be any positive real number ???

Comment: I think you may have valency and multiplier confused (or perhaps I do): https://imgur.com/a/Nle1s

Comment: I don't think the multiplier answers the question of "how many" fixpoints there are ? I used the name multiplicity because it's similar to counting the multiplicity of a zero or a pole, where you can say there are multiple zeros at a single point, just like you talk about "exactly one fixpoint at ...". It has little to do with the multiplier.

Comment: @mercio It still seems like it would be a nontrivial calculation to attempt to compute the multiplicity of a point of $R(z)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, your book has somewhere the definition of the multiplicity of a fixed point. If you don't have this definition it is completely pointless for you to think about this problem since it's talking about something about which you know nothing.

It should be something like this : If $f$ is defined on some open subset of $\Bbb C$ containing $0$ and $f(0)=0$, then the multiplicity of $0$ as a fixed point is the order of the zero of $f(z)-z$ at $0$, or more intuitively, to what order is $f$ similar to the identity at $0$.
Then you extend the definition to nonzero fixed points $a$ by conjugating $f$ with some automorphism $\tau$ that sends $0$ to $a$.

For this definition to make sense, this number has to be unchanged when you conjugate $f$ with some transformation $\tau$ invertible near $0$, satisfying $\tau(0)=0$. Proving this is a bit painful, but it works out in the end (I will skip it)

---

In your example, to apply this definition you need to conjugate $R(z)$ with the inversion $\tau(z) = z^{-1}$ and then study the multiplicity of $0$ as a fixed point of $R' = \tau^{-1} \circ R \circ \tau$.

Now, $R'(z) = \frac {b_0z^n + b_1z^{n-1} + \cdots + b_m z^{n-m}}{a_0z^n + a_1z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n}$.

Then,
$(a_0z^n + a_1z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n)(R'(z)-z) = \\
-a_0 z^{n+1} + ((b_0-a_1)z^n + \cdots + (b_m-a_{m+1})z^{n-m}) - (a_{m+2}z^{n-m-1} + \cdots + a_n z)$

$a_n$ is nonzero so the order of $0$  as a zero in the first factor is $0$, and so the multiplicity is the order of $0$ as a $0$ in the polynomial in the right hand side.

This multiplicity is exactly $1$ if and only if the coefficient of $z^1$ doesn't vanish (if it vanishes then the multiplicity is higher).

If $n=m+1$ then this coefficient is $b_m-a_{m+1} = b_m-a_n$, so in this case you need $b_m \neq a_n$.
If $n>m+1$ then this coefficient is $-a_n$, so in this case you need $a_n \neq 0$, which was already in the assumptions of the problem.

So the fixed point has multiplicity exactly $1$ if and only if $n>m+1$ or ($n=m+1$ and $b_m \neq a_n$)

---

One neat thing about this way of counting multiplicities is that a degree $n$ rational fraction that is not the identity should always have $n+1$ fixed points counted with multiplicity

Comment: Thats interesting.  In my above conjugation I just assumed that it was good enough to consider $S(z)=P(z)/Q(z)$.  Looking at $P(z)-zQ(z)=0$.  We can factor out $z$ from every term so we have one fixed point at 0.  So one fixed point at infinity.

Comment: Nevermind, I kept interpreting R' as a derivative.

Comment: Quick question, is there a small typo in the case of $n=m+1$.  I don't see exactly where the $b_n-a_m$ comes from.

Comment: you're right, $b_m - a_{m+1}$ is $b_m-a_n$ and not $b_n-a_m$